# Check what deleted multiple remote git branches

Tags: git, bitbucket

A few days ago I cleaned up about 150 branches from the remote we weren't using. I left a few (about 30) that we needed. Today coming to work I found that only 19 were left.

Is there a way I could check what/who deleted the branches that disappeared? I know I can resurrect them pushing a local copy that I can find with `git reflog`, but is there a way to check when/who/what deleted those 10 missing branches on the remote?

We are using bitbucket as a repository provider if that is of any help.

Comment: Either get a confession from the person who deleted them, or get the logs from the server (if there are any such logs—e.g., there might be a hook that emailed someone at the time).